# I need to run a PHP script I wrote as a task on my server

Tags: php, linux, ssh, cron

I need to run a PHP script which is scraping a website for data, and I need to run it on my VPS which has linux. I want to run it as a task so that I should be able to logout of my VPS and the script should keep running in background.

I've read about CRON job but it's more for like scheduling and repetitive tasks; but I need the PHP script only once.

Is there a way in PHP to do that? Please help, I'm just a newbie to this.

Thanks in advance! :)

I've tried it as a CRON job, but it doesn't seem to serve my exact purpose.

so I run my script like this from terminal.

```
php scrapethewebsite.php
```

and then it show this

```
Started scraping at 10:03:00 20-03-2019
```

and I can't logout or close my vps/ssh connection.

I look for

```
php scrapethewebsite.php
Started scraping at 10:03:00 20-03-2019
```

and then I should be able to logout or close my connection. And then I should be able to shutdown my PC and go for a walk..

Comment: i'll write a answer in a bit.. its called `nohup`

Comment: I wrote this a while ago https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/BgProcess.php - It can do background, non-blocking processes in both Linux and Windows from PHP.  I should mention what you can do is make a launcher, which is what you call.  In that piece of code you can then start the background process.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do this with the screen. The screen is most of the time already installed in Linux VPS. but still, you can get by command.

```
apt-get install screen
```

Its give you the ability to have multiple screens in VPS where you can run multiple tasks at the same time.
LIke you have.
Get a screen with command.

```
screen -S sessionname
```

sessionname will be ur screen name.
and you can dispach it with command/
CTRL + A, followed by D.
then you can close your putty or any tool from via you accessing your vps.
here you go.
for more information, you can follow this link.
[Screen in Linux](https://www.vultr.com/docs/using-screen-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your SSH session, then you can click X and close it and it will still run

```
nohup php scrapethewebsite.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

to check if your file is running type this command

```
top
```

you should see the php file up there and press spacebar to update the list

_____________________________________________________________________
If your php script has some error from time to time or just runs out of execution time and you want to re-run it when it closes down.. you have to create a `.sh` file with a while loop inside it and run `nohup` on it so it will re-run the php file after it errors up.

If you want to use `nohup` on php file that needs to re-run from time to time, then you should do the following

```
$ echo 'while true ; do php scrapethewebsite.php ; done > /dev/null' > ~/php_run_loop.sh
$ chmod a+x ~/php_run_loop.sh
$ nohup ~/php_run_loop.sh
```

**NOTE:** If you have an error or other problem in your php script, this will cause it to run over and over again without any limit, forever.